# What Sicilian Defence variation has the most similarity to the Dutch?

Tags: opening, sicilian-defense, dutch-defense

Given that in GM Simon William's book The Killer Dutch, Williams says that the Sicilian and the Dutch are mirror images of each other, as Williams states "If you look at the first move, you can see that the two openings are similar, due to the fact the initial pawn structures of both openings are actually mirror images of each other." (Williams, 32) What Sicilian Defence variation has the most similarity to the Dutch? In the sense of pawn structures, middlegame plans, and strategic ideas? From what I observe it seems to me like the Scheveningen is similar to the classical variation of the Dutch.

Which variation do you think is most similar?

Comment: It may be a mirror image left-to-right, but really, with the exception of playing on the side near the f/c-pawn, the similarities end there as far as I am concerned.

Comment: Which Dutch?  Leningrad and Classical are really quite different.  For frequency reasons, both of them are called Dutch, but that really makes about as much sense as calling both Nimzo-Indian and King's Indian the same opening because they both start 1. d4 Nf6

Comment: By the way, if they were remotely similar, the Dutch would be the most popular response to 1.d4, but it is a distant fourth.

Comment: Even `1.c4 e5` where King's pawn and Queen's bishop pawns are moved (just like Sicilian) is not very similar to Sicilian, and now you moved Queen pawn and Kings Bishop pawn. Dutch and Sicilian are very different.

Comment: They are definitely not similar. The only exception is closed sicilians compared to some classical dutches.

Answer (score 4):

"If you look at the first move, you can see that the two openings are similar, due to the fact the initial pawn structures of both openings are actually mirror images of each other."

That's one of the most patzerish things I've ever read in a book written by a strong player.

Flip the board around, and I don't think anyone (not even Simon Williams) would suggest the English and the Bird are similar, except that all four (Bird, English, Dutch, Sicilian) of them influence the center from the wing instead of through direct occupation, and none of them do as much for one's development as a central pawn move.

Answer (score 2):

The most similar variations probably come in some of the closed lines (Grand Prix, Closed Sicilian...) where each side plays in an opposite side of the board. The Morra Gambit is also "similar" to **1.d4 f5 2.e4** in the sense that White sacrifices a pawn for activity, but that's pretty much it. The fact that in the Sicilian White can freely play d2-d4 due to the queen defending d4 really makes things different.